# citrix GUI automation or packet injection?

Tags: python, automation, citrix, packet-injection

most of my job is on a citrix ICA app.
i work in a winsows enviroment.
among other things, i have to print 300 reports from my app weekly. i am trying to automate this task. i was using a screenshot automation tool called sikuli, but it is not portable form station to station.

i thought i might be able to inject packets and send the commands on that level. i was not able to read the packets i captured with whireshark or do anythin sensable with them.

i have expirence with python and if i get pointed in the right direction, i am pretty sure i can pull something off.

does anyone have any ideas on how to do this (i am leaning towards packet injection aat the moment, but am open to ideas).

thanks for the help,
sam

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of research, it cant be done. some manipulation like change window focus with the ICA COM object.